# Обновление Яндекс-карты после изменения координат метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Проект на react.
Версия АПИ 2.1.79.

Здравствуйте!

Есть задача осуществлять мониторинг передвижения транспорта, отображая машины на карте с помощью меток.

Координаты приходят с сервера и пробрасываются в компонент карты с помощью props.

Объекты управляются через objectManager.

Я удаляю объект из списка, а затем добавляю его снова с обновлёнными координатами.

```
objectManager.remove([objectId]);
objectManager.add(objectWithNewCoords);
```

При таком способе положение меток на карте не обновляется, только если изменить zoom или подвигать карту мышкой -- в общем, совершить какое-нибудь действие.

Чтобы позиции менялись самостоятельно, приходится использовать setTimeout.

```
objectManager.remove([mapUnitTrace.id]);
setTimeout(() => objectManager.add(objectWithNewCoords), 50);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обновить позицию метки после смены её координат?
Спасибо!

Компонент карты

```
const initOptions = {
  center: [],
  zoom: YaMapData.INIT_ZOOM,
};

function YaMap({ placemarks, mapUnitTrace }: IYandexMapProps) {
  const [yandexMap, setYandexMap] = useState(null);
  const [objectManager, setObjectManager] = useState(null);

  const initYandexMapAndObjectManager = () => {
    setYandexMap(new ymaps.Map(YaMapData.MAP_ID, initOptions));
    setObjectManager(new ymaps.ObjectManager());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (yandexMap && objectManager) {
      yandexMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    }
  }, [objectManager]);

  const loadAndAddYandexMapToGlobalScope = async (init) => {
    if (!window.ymaps) {
      await createAndLoadScript(YaMapData.API_SRC);
    }

    ymaps.ready(init);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAndAddYandexMapToGlobalScope(initYandexMapAndObjectManager);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.ymaps) {
      objectManager.add(placemarks);
      yandexMap.setBounds(objectManager.getBounds());
    }
  }, [placemarks]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapUnitTrace.id && placemarks) {
      const r = {
        type: 'Feature',
        id: mapUnitTrace.id,
        geometry: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: mapUnitTrace.geometry,
        },
        properties: {
          hintContent: 'Содержание всплывающей подсказки',
          balloonContent: 'Содержание балуна',
        },
      };

      objectManager.remove([mapUnitTrace.id]);
      setTimeout(() => objectManager.add(r), 50);
    }
  }, [mapUnitTrace]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.yandexMapWrapper}>
      <div
        id={YaMapData.MAP_ID}
        className={styles.yandexMap}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default YaMap;
```

Comment: Если необходимо обновить метку, может есть смысл обновлять её, а не добавлять? `objectManager.update(objectWithNewCoords);`

Comment: Не нашёл такого метода в документации https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/ref/reference/ObjectManager#methods-summary
Можете дать ссылку на него?

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно штатно менять координаты метки.

```
let marker = objectManager.objects.getById(mapUnitTrace.id);
marker.geometry.setCoordinates(newCoordinates);
```

Comment: Попробую, спасибо!